# Editing an exitsting Angular project in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to open and edit an existing Angular 2 project in **Visual Studio 2017 for Mac**.

In VS 2017 for Windows you just do the "Open Folder" as i understand. However cant find the "open folder" in Vs2017 for Mac.

I have Visual Studio Code and it works fine, but had a plan to make a try with the **vs 2017 for mac**.

Reading the documentation it's not saying anything about spa, "just" xamarin and .Core projects so it may not be supported.
Maybe someone else have figured it out already?

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not currently support opening a folder as a project. Also there is no Angular support in Visual Studio for Mac so VS Code might be a better bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe there will be some support in the future. However VS Code is also really good enough.

Comment: I expect VS Mac will have Angular support in the future since VS on Windows has it.